# Design for a folder scanning service

Tags: java, file-io

We have an old java app wrapped as a service that essentially is a while loop, which iterates through folders looking for new files being created.

Apart of being a little inconsistent with big files, it works well, but makes me wonder if this is still a very basic approach or if it is the only approach when it comes to "look for updates" apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 7, you can use the [WatchService API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html).  [This article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) provides a good introduction.

WatchService is more efficient than polling if the OS supports it, and it will automatically fall back to polling if the OS does not support any more advanced way of watching the file system for changes.

Comment: +1 this is exactly what I clicked on this question to post, too bad you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to stick with Java, you might try .NET's `FileSystemWatcher` class inside of the service instead of your java implementation.